# Evaluate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos(t)+\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos(t)^3\sin (t)^3)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, gre-exam

Evaluate: $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos(t)+\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos(t)^3\sin(t)^3)dt$$

I have tried substituting $t=\tan(\theta)$ and breaking up the $\cos(t)^3$ using $\cos(t)^2=1-\sin(t)^2$, but I can't figure it out.

This question is #21 from the Math subject GRE form GR1268.

Comment: @BCLC: which GRE exam is this from? The tag on its own doesn't have much information

Comment: @CarlMummert [This](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%201%20solutions.pdf)

Comment: Thanks; I think that info should be in the question, if it is going to be tagged as coming from a GRE.  @BCLC

Answer (score 5):

Think about the parity of the second summand. You're integrating over a symmetric interval around the origin.

Comment: So if $S(t)=\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos(t)^3\sin(t)^3$, then $S(-t)=-S(t)$, and therefore $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/4}S(t)dt=0$?

So the answer would be $\int cos(t)dt=sin(\pi/4)-sin(-\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Indeed. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos(t)+\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t))dt=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\cos(t)dt+\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t)dt$

Since $\hspace{0.2cm}$$\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t)$$\hspace{0.2cm}$  is odd function   and  $\hspace{0.2cm}$$\cos(t)$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ is even function  therefore

$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t)dt=0$

and

$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\cos(t)dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(t)dt$

Hence

$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos(t)+\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t))dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(t)dt=2(\sin(t))|_{0}^{\pi/4}=2\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$