# How to integrate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (\cos(t) + \sqrt{1 + t^2}\cos^3(t)\sin^3(t))\;\mathrm{d}t$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate

> $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (\cos{t} + \sqrt{1 + t^2}\cos^3{(t)}\sin^3{(t)})\;\mathrm{d}t$$

There's no substitution that immediately jumps out at me.

Comment: I think you can eliminate the first $\cos$

Comment: Sometimes questions about integration look funny. the integration region is symmetric, that makes me think about the "odd"ness of sin(t) and the "even"ess of cos(t).

Comment: @BCLC: please do not tag posts 'gre-exam' without saying the GRE exam that they came from

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524194/evaluate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1t2-cost3-sin-t3dt , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359037/how-to-integrate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1-t2-cos3t-sin3 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089218/how-to-solve-int-pi-4-pi-4-left-cosx-sqrt1x2-sin2x-cos2x ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341731/gre-sample-math-practice-book-problem-21-calculus?noredirect=1 ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220369/definite-integral-containing-2-trig-functions-and-a-square-root-function?noredirect=1 ,

Answer (score 3):

You don't need substitution for this one. Use the fact that $$\int_a ^b f(x)\;\mathrm{dx}=\int_a ^b f(a+b-x)\;\mathrm{dx}$$ So, replacing $t$ with $\frac {\pi}{4}+\frac {-\pi}{4}-t=-t$, we get $$I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\left (\cos{(-t)} + \sqrt{1 + (-t)^2}\cos^3{(-t)}\sin^3{(-t)}\right)\;\mathrm{dt}$$ or $$I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \left(\cos{(t)} - \sqrt{1 + t^2}\cos^3{(t)}\sin^3{(t)}\right)\;\mathrm{d}t$$ as $\cos (-x)=\cos x$ and $\sin (-x)=-\sin x$. We then get: $$\implies 2I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 2\cos{(t)} \;\mathrm{dt}\implies I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos{(t)} \;\mathrm{dt}$$ which means that $$I=\left(\sin \dfrac {\pi}4-\sin \left(\dfrac {-\pi}4 \right ) \right)=\sqrt 2$$

**EDIT:** A small *proof* of the **fact** mentioned above: Substitute $y=a+b-x$ in $\int_a ^b f(x)\;\mathrm{dx}$. The limits will now go from $b$ to $a$. The integral thus becomes $\int_b ^a f(a+b-y)(-\;\mathrm{dy})$ or $\int_a ^b f(a+b-y)\;\mathrm{dy}$.

Comment: What is the rule you cite at the top called? It seems somewhat obscure.

Comment: If you load this problem into wolfram alpha the integral does not equal zero @CobraCobra

Comment: @Nkris, the solution is edited. Now load it into WA.

Comment: $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos{(t)} dt$ is calculated wrong: I believe the antiderivative is $\sin(x)$, the plugging in $ \frac{\pi}{4} $and  $-\frac{\pi}{4} $we have $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) -\sin(\frac{-\pi}{4}) = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: @MaxLipton, look at the edit.

Comment: @Nkris, edited.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t)=\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3 t\sin ^3 t$ and note that $f(-t)=-f(t)$.  That is $f$ is an odd function.  Note that when we integrate any odd, integrable function around symmetric limits we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^af(t)\,dt&=\int_{-a}^0f(t)\,dt+\int_0^af(t)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^af(-t)\,dt+\int_0^af(t)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^a(-f(t))\,dt+\int_0^af(t)\,dt\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Thus, for $f(t)=\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3 t\sin ^3 t$ and $a=\pi/4$ we have

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3 t\sin ^3 t \,dt=0$$

Finally,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos t+\sqrt{1+t^2}\cos^3 t\sin ^3 t)\,dt=\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the second part is an odd function over $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$, which means...

Comment: @downvoter. Would you care to explain the reason to downvote?

Comment: I don't understand the motivation of the trigger happy down voter.  I will neutralize because $(1)$ the answer/hint is actually useful and $(2)$ I don't appreciate the down vote syndrome herein.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank u very much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!