# integrate $\cos(x)+\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^3(x)\cos^3(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods

Need help integrating this monster. I dont see any way to do it by analysis there must be a numerical process to do it or some neat functions trick but I can't seem to spot it. Many thanks:

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\cos(x)+\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^3(x)\cos^3(x)\right) dx$$

the answer is $\sqrt{2}$ if that helps.

Comment: I did my best to interpret what you meant. Please make sure I did not make a mistake.

Comment: Split the integral up. The bounds should give you a hint as to how to simplify the rightmost integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524194/evaluate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1t2-cost3-sin-t3dt , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359037/how-to-integrate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1-t2-cos3t-sin3 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089218/how-to-solve-int-pi-4-pi-4-left-cosx-sqrt1x2-sin2x-cos2x ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341731/gre-sample-math-practice-book-problem-21-calculus?noredirect=1 ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220369/definite-integral-containing-2-trig-functions-and-a-square-root-function?noredirect=1

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Given integral is equivalent to
$$
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\cos x dx.\quad(\text{why?})
$$

Comment: Good answer! I just made the bounds a touch easier to read. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick edit @choco, i was spending 20min+ trying to figure it out only to read error choco already edited this part of the body haha. as for the integral being the same as cosx dx is it because taking cosx common we get 1+sqrt(1+x^2)sin^3(x)cos^2(x) and sin^3(x) is [1-cos^2(x)] sqrt(1-cosx) and yea im not sure why. am i on the right track that taking cosx common and some trig manipulation leads to the other factor being 1?

Comment: I didn't approach that way, because integrating given formula directly is too hard. Instead, you can observe that $\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^3 x \cos^3 x$ is an odd function.

Comment: ah so the symmetrical integral over -a to a will be 0. nice catch choco_addicted. thanks again! love this community, im a newcomer and I can see myself returning often :D